# Change object animation become cyclic for many objects, use Python

Tags: python, animation

I use Python for create many objects then give them animation key frame like this (no problem here):

```
object.location = (x, y , z)
object.keyframe_insert(data_path='location', frame=start, index=-1)
object.location = (x + changeX, y + changeY, z + changeZ)
object.keyframe_insert(data_path='location', frame=end, index=-1)
```

How change animation become cyclic? I already know graph editor can change it, but how change this use Python for each object when add their key frames? I try:

```
bpy.ops.graph.extrapolation_type(type='MAKE_CYCLIC')
```

but Blender tell 'failed, context is incorrect'

Answer (score 2):

Get fcurve array for object

```
fc = object.animation_data.action.fcurves
```

From list find fcurve want repeat (example location X)

```
locationX = fc.find('location', index=0)
```

Create modifier type CYCLES and set mode_before and mode_after become REPEAT

```
modifier = locationX.modifiers.new(type='CYCLES')
modifier.mode_before = 'REPEAT'
modifier.mode_after = 'REPEAT'
```

One problem, this method cause two repeat loops between original two keyframes, object move 1/2 time and 1/2 distance between keyframes. Need double original distance and time between key frames.